# Need to Update Product Media Gallery Image Label

Tags: magento-1.9, media-images

I am trying to update the media gallery image label with **product_id**. I have tried different different codes but didn't get any chance to update the image label. Is there any way of updating media gallery image label programmatically or using csv file ? I am using magento version 1.9.3.X

My Code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(1);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::init();



$productId = 142;
//load the product
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);


$i = 1;
foreach($product->getData('media_gallery') as $each){
    foreach($each as $image){
        $i++;
        $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getSetAttributes($product);
    $attributes['media_gallery']->getBackend()->updateImage($product, $image['file'], $data=array('postion'=>$i,'label_default'=>'labelnametext'));
    }
}
$product->save();
```

IF anyone have any idea please share with me.

Thanks

Comment: tell us what you have tried so far, put a code sample over here

Comment: please check my code for single product only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code.

```
<?php 

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product_id = 142; //Your Product Id
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
$gallery = $attributes['media_gallery'];
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $image->getValueId().' - '.$image->getLabel();
    $backend = $gallery->getBackend();
    if($image->getValueId() == 'value_id of image 1'){
        $backend->updateImage(
            $product,
            $image->getFile(),
            array('label' => 'image-label1')
        );
    }
    if($image->getValueId() == 'value_id of image 2'){
        $backend->updateImage(
            $product,
            $image->getFile(),
            array('label' => 'image-label2')
        );  
    }
}
$product->setMediaGalleryImages($images);
$product->save();
```

Comment: Yes Thanks its worked. But it saves same label name for each image. I want to update diff -2 label name for each image.

Comment: You can set the image label for multiple images with the help of `value_id`. Check my updated code. And if it works, you can hit the Upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

I think `$product->save()` give you fatal error , try to save Attribute please check answer for detail , and also set admin store for saving detail otherwise you get error store not found.

```
       Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); // set Admin store for your script Otherwise you get Fatal error 
       $product = mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(16);
       $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
       $gallery = $attributes['media_gallery'];
       $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
       foreach ($images as $image) {
          $backend = $gallery->getBackend();
          $backend->updateImage(
             $product,
             $image->getFile(),
             array('label' => 'Blah')
         );
      }
  $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'media_gallery'); //Attribute Save
```

Comment: I have tried this one also but didnt update the value. thanks for your reply

Comment: OK got it your issue give me 10 min I will update the code

Comment: @Ch037 please check updated code

Comment: sorry its also didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sku =  "test";   //$value[0]; echo "<br>"; 
 $product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku );



            if(is_object($product) )
            {

                  $baseImage                  =  $value[1];
                  $fullBaseImage              = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'import'.DS.'HSD-optimized-images-toupload-1'.DS.$baseImage; 

                  $additionalImage            =  $value[2];
                  $fullAdditionalImage        = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'import'.DS.'HSD-optimized-images-toupload-1'.DS.$additionalImage;


                $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
                $media_gallery = $attributes['media_gallery'];
                $backend = $media_gallery->getBackend();
                $backend->afterLoad($product);
                $count = count($product->getMediaGalleryImages()) + 1; 



                  if($baseImage!='' && is_file($fullBaseImage)  )
                  {
                        $media_attributes = array('image','small_image','thumbnail');
                        $filename = $media_gallery->getBackend()->addImage($product, $fullBaseImage, $media_attributes,false, false);
                        $attributes['media_gallery']->getBackend()->updateImage($product, $filename, array('position' => $count));
                        $product->save();


                  }
                  else if($additionalImage!='' && is_file($fullAdditionalImage)  )
                  {
                        $filename = $media_gallery->getBackend()->addImage($product, $fullAdditionalImage, null,false, false);
                        $attributes['media_gallery']->getBackend()->updateImage($product, $filename, array('position' => $count));
                        $product->save();

                  }


            }
```